# Reasons of Pod Status Failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, kube-controller-manager

If Pod's status is `Failed`, Kubernetes will try to create new Pods until it reaches `terminated-pod-gc-threshold` in `kube-controller-manager`. This will leave many `Failed` Pods in a cluster and need to be cleaned up.

Are there other reasons except `Evicted` that will cause Pod `Failed`?

Comment: What does `kubectl describe pod NAME` say? Please add the output to your question. Are the health checks for the pod configured correctly? Can you show their configuration?

Comment: @John I haven't seen other reasons except `Evicted` that cause Pod `Failed` and want to know if there're other reaons :D

Comment: Oh, so it's more of a theoretical question?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if anyone has seen reasons other than `Evicted` that cause Pod `Failed`.

Answer (score 6):

There can be many causes for the POD status to be `FAILED`. You just need to check for problems(if there exists any) by running the command

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe pod <pod-name>
```

Carefully check the `EVENTS` section where all the events those occurred during POD creation are listed. Hopefully you can pinpoint the cause of failure from there.

However there are several reasons for POD failure, some of them are the following:

- Wrong image used for POD.
- Wrong command/arguments are passed to the POD.
- Kubelet failed to check POD liveliness(i.e., liveliness probe failed).
- POD failed health check.
- Problem in network CNI plugin (misconfiguration of CNI plugin used for networking).

For example:
[image: pod failed due to image pull error]

In the above example, the image "not-so-busybox" couldn't be pulled as it doesn't exist, so the pod FAILED to run. The pod status and events clearly describe the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this:

```
kubectl get pods <pod_name> -o yaml
```

And in the output, towards the end, you can see something like this:

[image]

This will give you a good idea of where exactly did the pod fail and what happened.

Answer (score 2):

PODs will not survive scheduling failures, node failures, or other evictions, such as lack of resources, or in the case of node maintenance.
Pods should not be created manually but almost always via controllers like Deployments (self-healing, replication etc).

Reason why pod failed or was terminated can be obtain by

```
kubectl describe pod <pod_name>
```

Others situation I have encountered when pod Failed:

- Issues with image (not existing anymore)
- When pod is attempting to access i.e ConfigMap or Secrets but it is not found in namespace.
- Liveness Probe Failure
- Persistent Volume fails to mount
- Validation Error

In addition, eviction is based on resources - [EvictionPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#eviction-policy)

It can be also caused by DRAINing the Node/Pod. You can read about DRAIN [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/).